# how to change display width of datalist

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

i have a simple issue with HTML datalist but somehow cant solve this problem.
i've tried to change the displayed width for the following datalist:

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="this is a really long name for a browser">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
  </datalist>
<input type="submit">
```

but no matter what i try, it still cuts down the "long" option values.
how can i change that, so that the datalist shows all the option values, no matter how long they are?

best regards

Comment: Which browser are you using to view the page? For me it's working in chrome.
And do you want to change the option field's width dynamically for longer texts?

Comment: It's a browser shell. E.G. in Chrome you can read whole value text but in FireFox it's cropped to input width. The only cross-browser solution is to:
**a)** make input wider to make sure whole value is readable: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/rpeubzke/)
**b)** use (or write) some JavaScript to emulate `datalist` so you can have full control over it's appearance.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply :) guess my problem cant be solved in an easy way atm. i'll try select2 then i guess. again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser" style="width: 100px;">

  <datalist id="browsers">
   <option value="this is a really long name for a browser">
   <option value="Firefox">
   <option value="Chrome">
   <option value="Internet Explorer">
  </datalist>

<input type="submit">
```

Comment: I tried it for 1000px; but the dropdown option does not match

Comment: It seems `<input list="browsers" name="browser" style="width: 100px;">` works for input box, but not droplist

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't have a standardized way of displaying datalists yet (and some browsers may not even support it.)  If you're looking for a polyfill, the "remote-list" jQuery plugin uses a webshim to add features that provide a consistent look-and-feel.  I tested the webshim/datalist combination using BrowserStack.com and Firefox, Chrome, iOS 9, Android 4.3, IE8/9/10/11/Edge all appear to function and not be constrained to the width of the parent INPUT field.

https://github.com/aFarkas/remote-list

https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim

NOTE: The webshim developer has indicated that he's not planning on developing a new major version to be compatible w/jQuery 3.0.

Answer (score -6):

this example  works

```
   <input list="cropBeds" id="myCropBeds" name="listCropBeds" />
   <datalist id="cropBeds">
    <option value="TO">
    <option value="TM">
    <option value="TE">
    <option value="TS">
    <option value="LT">
    <option value="JT">
   </datalist>
```

with a css file

```
   input[name='listCropBeds']{width: 30px;}
```

the inspiration for this is there: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRjzKg

Comment: This doesn't work if you set `input[name="browsers"].width: 1000px;` for example. https://codepen.io/mangelikam/pen/KKgKBKM